# Flutter app theme does not get changed depending on the image

Tags: flutter, themes

I've a flutter app where there is a functionality to implement which is to change the app colors when the logo of brand is changed. I've successfully been able to fetch the colors from the image using palete generator package and even if I try to check them manually they are okay, but app theme does not get updated. Please let me know.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:palette_generator/palette_generator.dart';

class Themes {
  static getTheme(Image? image, context) async {
    var primaryColor;
    var accentColor;
    var backgroundColor;

    if (image == null) {
      print('Color fetch failed');
      primaryColor = Color.fromRGBO(50, 97, 255, 0.9);
      accentColor = Colors.white;
      backgroundColor = Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 1);
    } else {
      final colors = await _fetchColorsFromImage(image) as List<Color>;

      final color1 = colors.elementAt(0);
      primaryColor = Color(_getHexOf(color1.toString()));
      accentColor = colors[1];
      backgroundColor = colors[2];
      print('Primary: ${primaryColor.toString()}');
      print('Accent: ${accentColor.toString()}');
      print('Background: ${backgroundColor.toString()}');
    }

    return ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
        background: backgroundColor,
        primary: primaryColor,
        onPrimary: accentColor,
        secondary: accentColor,
        onSecondary: accentColor,
      ),
    );
  }

  static _fetchColorsFromImage(Image image) async {
    final List<Color> colorsList = [];
    final generator = await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(image.image);
    if (generator.vibrantColor != null) {
      colorsList.add(generator.vibrantColor!.color);
    }

    if (generator.mutedColor != null) {
      colorsList.add(generator.mutedColor!.color);
    }

    if (generator.dominantColor != null) {
      colorsList.add(generator.dominantColor!.color);
    }

    return colorsList;
  }

  static int _getHexOf(String color) {
    final hex = color.replaceAll('Color(', '');
    return int.parse(hex.substring(0, hex.length - 1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by wrapping your MaterialApp() to AnimatedBuilder
() will help to change theme run time you can get a better idea of this **flutter skeleton template**

**flutter create --template app** it will generate a sample of  theme change and other stuffs

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work